The Gnome extension-manager lists all extensions as unsupported
I've been trying to install the "Auto Move Windows" extension for gnome but every method I've tried has failed, including via browser and manually putting the extracted extension folder where all of the extensions would be. Unfortunately I haven't been able to use any gnome extensions via any method, but the most promising was through the extension-manager, which shows me a list of all of the available extensions, but lists them as unsupported and won't install them (pictured below):

This has been very frustrating as I would also like to use extensions in general, but this problem has happened no matter how I install the application (via software, terminal, or flatpak) and has persisted after restarting. I'm using 64-bit ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS using Gnome 42.9 and X11. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Does this answer your question? GNOME extension is incompatible

There are good reasons for not installing unsupported gnome shell extensions
As you see in vanadium's answer in GNOME extension is incompatible There are problems with enabling gnome shell extensions that are not compatible.
But if you wish to enable anyway use:
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-extension-version-validation true
Source: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/06/gnome-extension-incompatible/.
Make sure that you document for yourself what you did and which shell extension you used, so that if it or something else breaks you know the reason.
